# Click on button to reply an email in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, email

I have a form. When user fills and submits. It will send a mail to department head with an attachment of the form. This email has two buttons 'Approve' & 'Reject'. Now When the manager 'Approves', it should reply with Approval message and an attachment. However when he click on 'Reject', should reply with message 'Rejected'. Below is what I have now.

PHP to send the application to the manager. I am using PHP mailer
PHP

```
  $body = file_get_contents('Source/auth.php'); // Authentication Page
  $mail = new PHPMailer();        
  $mail->IsSMTP(); 
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->Port = 465; // or 465
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->Username = $_SESSION['member_name'];
  $mail->Password = $_SESSION['member_password'];
  $mail->SetFrom($_SESSION['member_name']);
  $mail->Subject = "Application";
  $mail->Body = $body;
  $mail->AddAddress($memail);// Manager of the Department from DB
  $mail->AddReplyTo($memEmail, "name"); // Reply mail
  $mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Application/PDF/'.$file.'.pdf');
  $mail->Send(header ('Location: login_succ.php'));
```

I have created a small Authentication page 'auth.php'; included in the mail by the sender.
HTML

```
<form name="form1" method="GET" action="" onSubmit="return verify()">
    <div>
            <button>Approved</button> // Reply with approval form as attachment
        <button>Rejected</button> // Reply 'Rejected'
        </div>
</form>
```

Is this achievable? I would like to send the application on internet as well as intranet.

Comment: Give the buttons different values and then check to see which one was passed.

Comment: Ok, so I should embedd PHP tags in between the mail and use values to achieve the approve/ reject is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some like with this:

```
<form name="form1" method="GET" action="" onSubmit="return verify()">
    <div>
        <button class="bt" action="aprove">Approved</button> // Reply with approval form as attachment
        <button class="bt" action="reject">Rejected</button> // Reply 'Rejected'
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".bt").click(function(event) {

    var action = $(this).attr("action");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/fileEmail.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {action: 'action'},
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });

});
});

</script>

<?php
//File fileEmail.php
$action = $_POST["action"];

if($action == "aprove"){
    $message = "Some msg to aprove";
    $attachment = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Application/PDF/aprove.pdf';
}else if($action == "reject"){
    $message = "Some msg to reject";
    $attachment = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Application/PDF/reprove.pdf';
}

$mail = new PHPMailer();        
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; // or 465
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = $_SESSION['member_name'];
$mail->Password = $_SESSION['member_password'];
$mail->SetFrom($_SESSION['member_name']);
$mail->Subject = "Application";
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AddAddress($memail);// Manager of the Department from DB
$mail->AddReplyTo($memEmail, "name"); // Reply mail
$mail->AddAttachment($attachment);
$mail->Send(header ('Location: login_succ.php'));
```

Second case:

The content into e-mail:

```
<a href="http://www.yoururl.com/fileEmail.php?action=aprove"></a>
<a href="http://www.yoururl.com/fileEmail.php?action=reject"></a>
```

The content into fileEmail.php in your server:

```
<?php
//File in your server: http://www.yoururl.com/fileEmail.php
$action = $_GET["action"];

//Create a authentication for your user
$auth = someMethodToAuth(); //If ok, register the sessions to send email
if(!$auth){
    die("You dont have permission to access this page!");
}

if($action == "aprove"){
    $message = "Some msg to aprove";
    $attachment = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Application/PDF/aprove.pdf';
}else if($action == "reject"){
    $message = "Some msg to reject";
    $attachment = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Application/PDF/reprove.pdf';
}

$mail = new PHPMailer();        
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; // or 465
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = $_SESSION['member_name'];
$mail->Password = $_SESSION['member_password'];
$mail->SetFrom($_SESSION['member_name']);
$mail->Subject = "Application";
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AddAddress($memail);// Manager of the Department from DB
$mail->AddReplyTo($memEmail, "name"); // Reply mail
$mail->AddAttachment($attachment);
$mail->Send(header ('Location: login_succ.php'));
```

Comment: This is Correct but, how we will achieve the reply by clicking approve. When clicking approve the mail should go as a reply. So that each user can apply for the approval and manager can approve or reject accordingly.

Comment: Syntactic error when I place the Javascript inside the PHP, it shows in Dreamweaver. However if I keep it outside it is not passing variables.

Comment: I updated. The `$(document).ready(function(){`. The open and close tag.